# Installation Requirements

Tags: 14.04, system-requirements

Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 having these

Memory       1GB
Processor    AMD sempron Processor 3000+
Graphics     Gallium 0.4 on NV4C
OS Type      32 bit 
HDD          500GB

Comment: Also, if you have "_Gallium 0.4_" listed as graphics card, I'd avoid the standard version of Ubuntu with Unity, as the performance of software rendering for graphics is abysmal. Use Lubuntu or another lightweight variant of Ubuntu instead.

Comment: @JonasCz can I use 13.04?

Comment: You should use the latest version, 16.04, as 13.04 is no longer supported. But you should use one of the lightweight variants, such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

Comment: @JonasCz is there any other lightweight variants rather than Lubuntu?

Comment: Yes, there's [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) and [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/).

Answer (score 1):

1GB memory size is very low for Ubuntu.  Either install at least one more, for the 32-bit version or use Lubuntu 32-bit instead.

Comment: 1GB is perfectly fine for Ubuntu :). Maybe not GNOME or KDE, but Ubuntu is designed to work with older systems.

Comment: @Zacharee1, Not for the standard version with Unity, IMO. I tried it and it struggles with even basic web browsing - Unity can use ~500MB + on it's own.

Comment: @JonasCz - Lubuntu though...